# Scroll для AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-scrollview, android-ui

Как сделать прокручивание содержимого AlertDialog?

Добавлял, не работает

```
 header.setScroller(new Scroller(getActivity()));
 header.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
 header.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Код:

```
private void setListeners() {
    view.findViewById(R.id.create_new_space).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
            View promptView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.onboarding_dialog_create_space, null);
            TextView header = (TextView) promptView.findViewById(R.id.header_dialog);
            header.setText(type + " name");
            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptView);
            EditText newName = (EditText) promptView.findViewById(R.id.input_name);
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            if (newName.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0 && mStorage != null) {
                                mStorage.open();
                                mStorage.writeSpaces(type, newName.getText().toString().trim(), null);
                                mStorage.close();
                                invoker.callYourSpace(newName.getText().toString().trim(), type);
                            }
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
            AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
            alert.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
            alert.show();
        }
    });
}
```

XML

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp">

<com.firstalert.onelink.utils.GothamTextView
    android:id="@+id/header_dialog"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="Home Name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/onelink_dark_blue"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<com.firstalert.onelink.utils.GothamTextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:text="This is the space where the alarm is installed"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="@color/onelink_dark_blue"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/input_name"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.37"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_edittext"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:textColor="@color/onelink_dark_blue"
    android:textColorLink="@color/onelink_dark_blue"
    android:maxLines="1"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оберните все, что у вас в `onboarding_dialog_create_space.xml` в `ScrollView`.
Вот пример реализации:

```
<ScrollView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textmsg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

## UPD#1 Зачем нужен атрибут `android:fillViewport`?

У нашего *ScrollView* в `layout_height` стоит `fill_parent`. Это совсем не то, что нужно, когда мы работаем со *ScrollView*. Какой толк от *ScrollView*, если его содержание будет совпадать по высоте? В таком случае нам нечего скроллить. Решить эту проблему можно с помощью атрибута `android:fillViewport`. Когда он установлен в **true** - содержимое *ScrollView* будет растягиваться на всю его высоту, но только в том случае, если оно помещается. Если же контент по высоте не помещается - поведение остается стандартным, вьюху можно скроллить как обычно.

Comment: Все равно не скроллит, добавил скриншот.

Comment: @user233428 лучше добавьте листинг файла разметки `onboarding_dialog_create_space.xml`

Comment: добавил листинг

Comment: @user233428 добавьте в ScrollView `android:fillViewport="true"`

Comment: все заработало, спасибо большое

Comment: @Lex Hobbit, а можете обьяснить пожалуйста зачем этот атрибут?

Comment: @Flippy добавил upd#1

Comment: @Len Hobbit, класс, спасибо, а то в практике ни разу не сталкивался )